# A central way to handle python supervisors

Tags: python, plone, supervisord, zope

Is there a way to handle a bunch of supervisors on a single server in a central way?

We would like to restart all instances of all supervisors with a single
command for python updates and for hotfixes.

For example:

```
$ supersupervisor <project> <command> <group>
$ supersupervisor all restart zopes
```

This would restart all zope instances of all configured supervisors but if you have more than one instance it would restart them in a save way which means it restarts for example instance2, waits for it to come back and then restarts instance1.

Comment: You don't you simply use a single supervisor for rule them all? A supervisor can handle more than a single buildout.
Or you are talking about instances distributed on more that one server?

Comment: We started [papavisor](https://github.com/webmeisterei/papavisor>) it shows what we want to archive and tried to get infos from others first.

Comment: Correct link [papavisor](https://github.com/webmeisterei/papavisor)

Comment: Who watches the watchmen?